# Real-world advantage of namespace aliases vs defines

Tags: c++, namespaces, macros, coding-style, c-preprocessor

EDIT: I'm planing to refactor some code, and replace the `define` with a namespace alias. I can't do this though just because "macros are evil". I need to explain *why* I want to make the change and *what* can go wrong if I don't.

Leaving aside the stance that "macros are evil", what are the downfalls of `#define` over a namespace alias?

Take the code

```
#define MY_NAMESPACE my_namespace
```

versus

```
namespace MY_NAMESPACE = my_namespace;
```

The reason for having aliases is not in the scope of the question. You can also assume the name of the namespace is unique enough that it doesn't appear anywhere else (i.e. it just refers to that namespace, it can't - not now, not in the future - refer to a variable or a class or whatever), so there can be no ambiguity there.

Comment: Macros are evil.

Comment: @KerrekSB sometimes, just sometimes, that's not a good enough reason for a refactor.

Comment: among competing hypotheses, the simplest one should be selected.

Comment: "You can also assume the name of the namespace is unique enough that it doesn't appear anywhere else" -- then this is a pretty academic exercise. I take it you never reuse code from previous projects?

Comment: @larsmans I meant that as "there is nothing else with the same name"

Comment: "You can also assume...": Using properly scoped language-level identifiers, rather than letting the preprocessor vomit all over the code with no respect for scope, you don't need to make any such assumptions.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Not sure why this has been marked as 'not constructive'. Admitedly this is a duplicate of all `#define` vs. anything else, since the pitfalls are the same (i.e. macros are context insensitive, will replace the word where you want and where you don't...) but I would not categorize this as 'not constructive'

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas it's not really the same (and I excluded those pitfalls by my assumptions). I already know about the other questions. :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No, it is exactly the same. In any other case where someone might consider a `#define` they can make the same assumptions, and that does not guarantee that two months from now you won't start using a library that has that same word in some header, or someone might add a variable by the same name... The question and answer are exactly the same, `#define`'s is a hammer that will drive nails and screws (and smash any other thing in the process), namespace aliases are a screwdriver that applies only to screws.

Comment: Given your use-case: if the macro is only defined on a TU-basis then it will probably be fine. Otherwise the usual pitfalls are good enough to argue for refactoring.

Comment: I read this question to be "How can I persuade someone to sponsor me in terms of time and money to replace code (which is presumably already working) with a better solution that they may not see the significance of, probably will result in no immediate tangible benefit and may even - since every code change involves risk - increase the risk of problems in the short term?" - If it was along these lines then I think it is a constructive question. I face these issues every day.

Comment: @Component10 way to read between the lines :)

Comment: I'm not a fan of the verbiage ('not constructive'). I prefer 'not a good fit.' As our [About page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page says, this question has the following issues: "**Requests for lists of things**, polls, **opinions**, **discussions**, etc."  This is a request for a list of disadvantages of `#define`. Also, this question (as the comments have already born out) will elicit opinions and discussion, which makes it not a good fit for this site. The fact that it's apparently been asked before is just sauce for the goose.  You can always vote to re-open, or take your case to meta.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker perhaps it's the wording that makes it sound like that, but that wasn't the intention. It's not a request for a list of disadvantages, I already went through those and none apply in my case. I'm asking whether someone came head-to-head with a situation where a define like this messed things up, so that I can present it as an example of things to come.

Comment: I would suggest that if it's so hard to justify, maybe it's really not worth doing in the end. We don't live in a perfect world.

Comment: @MarkRansom damn! Can't say I wasn't expecting that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this particular case, it depends.  If using a namespace alias
does the trick, by all means prefer it to macros, for all of the
usual reasons.  But the two do radically different things.  You
cannot open a namespace using its alias, i.e.:

```
namespace XYZ_ver1 {}
namespace XYZ = XYZ_ver1;

namespace XYZ {     //  Illegal!
}
```

This works with a macro; in fact, you can define the macro
before the namespace has ever appeared.  If you need this, then
you need to use a macro.

Comment: Excellent! I never thought about this.

Comment: I chose to see this as an advantage to using aliases - you restrict extending the namespace (unless you use the original name)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Agreed.  I define a macro in the library code itself, so that I don't have to change every `XYZ_ver1` in `XYZ_ver2`, but I provide the alias in the client interface, so the client can't (accidentally or otherwise) add to it.  (But my point was, partially at least, that his proposed change is not anodyne.)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the only advantage I see with namespace aliases is that they can be anywhere. Take the following example:

```
namespace a
{
    namespace that_is_a_great_namespace
    {
        namespace b = that_is_a_great_namespace;
    }
}

namespace that_is_a_great_namespace {}
```

You won't be able to define a macro that will convert `a::that_is_a_great_namespace` to `a::b` with no side effect. Here, `that_is_a_great_namespace` will also be converted to `b`. Namespace aliases help to resolve name conflicts in those cases.

However, if you already use `#defines` and it already works, refactoring your code for such a rare case may not be useful.